# Is there any thing like origin point in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d, cannon.js

Please I want to know if there is anything like origin point in three.js just as we have it in Blender, please I have tried to do a research on this topic but to no avail. I want to make a pinball game, it does not make any sense if the origin point of the paddle that strikes the ball to be at the middle of the object, it has to be at the left or right side of it (it affects how the object rotates). So please Is there a way of changing an object's origin point as we we can to in Blender or After Effects. A kind of pivot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least 2 ways you could do this.

Option 1

One is to use [BufferGeometry.translate()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate) to translate your geometry so the pivot point is where you want it.

Option 2

Another is to use a hierarchy of objects:

- Have a parent object, which you will rotate.  This could be a [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group).
- Create the Mesh as a child object of the parent, using [add()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.add) and set the position of the child Mesh so that the point you want the mesh to pivot about is at the origin of the parent object.

I most situations I'd probably go for option 2, as it's generally more flexible and easier to manipulate Object3Ds.  Manipulating the geometry tends to be a bit lower-level and it can be harder to diagnose problems.